# Looker Studio Filter: RegExp Contains (how to escape + signs)?

Tags: looker-studio

I'm working on a report in Google Looker Studio. The report pulls in data from Google Analytics 4. I'm trying to list a report on certain link_click events, using a filter.

My question is, how would I filter a link that contains this URL? https://www.google.com/maps?q=123+St+Augustine+Pl+Andrews%2C+California+918392

I thought I could use the RegExp Contains filter and put in "St+Augustine+Pl+Andrews" but that doesn't show anything. I tried escaping the + signs with "St+Augustine+Pl+Andrews" but it still doesn't show anything. If I just use one word, like "Augustine", it works. However, I may have other links with that single word that I don't want to show up, so I need more. I just can't figure out how to filter the plus signs. Please help! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You may try:

```
IF(REGEXP_MATCH(URL,".*St\\+Augustine\\+Pl\\+Andrews.*"),URL,"")
```

[image]